# Developer unable to create repository despite source repository administrator role

Tags: google-cloud-source-repos

I have assigned the Source Repository Administrator to a team member in Google Source Repositories for a Google Cloud project, but they're still unable to create a new repository in this project.

Would love to hear some suggestions if anyone else has faced a similar issue.

Comment: I understand that you assigned Source Repository Administrator to another team member( which has a Google Account ) or created a service account for him. The team member is not able to create the repository from his project. Can you post the error message when he fails?

Comment: @marian.vladoi They see a popup toast saying "Repository creation failed"

Comment: I just spent 15 minutes wondering why I couldn't create a repo via gcloud for a project I own. I finally realized I accidentally `gcloud config project set aprojectname` to the display name of the project and not the project_id (`gcloud projects list`), which proceeds but gives a yellow warning I missed. I made the mistake because I thought the project name was unique (which could be a common/your issue)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the `sourcerepo` API hadn't been enabled for the project.

Once done (e.g. `gcloud services enable sourcerepo.googleapis.com --project=<project-id>`, all was well.

Answer (score 0):

1. I created a new project 'repo'.
2. I assigned the permissions to the new user in the 'repo' project:

   ```
   gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding repo --member user:user@gmail.com --role roles/source.admin
   ```
3. I checked the 'repo' project to have the following services account:

   ```
   service-1111111@sourcerepo-service-accounts.iam.gserviceaccount.com (Cloud Source Repositories Service Agent for Project 754848704710 ) Role: Cloud Source Repositories Service Agent

   user@gmai.com  Role: Source Repository Administrator
   ```
4. I login to user@gmail.com project and run the command:

   ```
   gcloud source repos create  test_repo --project repo 
   Created [test_repo].
   ```
5. I login to 'repo' project and run the command:

   ```
   gcloud source repos list
   test_repo  repo  https://source.developers.google.com/p/repo/r/test_repo
   ```

Everything worked as expected for me.

> Cloud Source Repositories uses Cloud Identity and Access Management to
>   grant permissions to users. If a user cannot perform a specific
>   action, such as create a new repository, check to ensure they have the
>   correct IAM permissions